# I receive a (TypeError) when I try to access a nested array of hashes

Tags: ruby, typeerror

Let's say I work for a rock climbing gym and I am trying to make the attendance process easier. Here I am trying to access the `age` values within hashes that are in an array nested in a hash. Though I receive the proper output number of "belayers", I also get a TypeError for the line `parties[:attendance].each do |kid|`. I understand that this is wrong but I'm unsure how to fix it. Any advice would be useful.

```
def kids_hash
  kids_hash = {
    :party_one =>{
      :facilitator => 'Erica',
      :attendance => [
      {name: 'Harry', age: 6, wavers: 'yes', harness: "red", shoe_size: 3},
      {name: 'Frankie', age: 9, wavers: 'yes', harness: "blue", shoe_size: 7},
      {name: 'Gale', age: 4, wavers: 'yes', harness: "red", shoe_size: 3},
      {name: 'Rony', age: 4, wavers: 'no', harness: "red", shoe_size: 2},
      {name: 'Julia', age: 10, wavers: 'yes', harness: "blue", shoe_size: 9},
      {name: 'Sarah', age: 3, wavers: 'no', harness: "red", shoe_size: 13},
      {name: 'James', age: 3, wavers: 'yes', harness: "red", shoe_size: 2},
      {name: 'Kevin', age: 5, wavers: 'yes', harness: "red", shoe_size: 3},
      {name: 'Jessie', age: 11, wavers: 'yes', harness: "blue", shoe_size: 10}
      ]
    },
    :party_two => "not booked yet"
  }
end

def num_belayers
  kid_count = 0
  baby_count= 0
  kids_hash.values.each do |parties|
    parties[:attendance].each do |kid|
      if kid[:age] >= 5 
          kid_count += 1
        else
          baby_count +=1
        end
      end

    #if the kids are 5 y/o, we put 5 to a group
    belays_kids = kid_count / 5.00

    #if they are younger, there are 3 to a group
    belays_babies = baby_count / 3.00
    belays = belays_kids.ceil + belays_babies.ceil

    puts "You will need #{belays} belayers."
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you share the entire error?

Comment: You will need 3 belayers.
party_time.rb:27:in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
 from party_time.rb:27:in `block in num_belayers'
 from party_time.rb:26:in `each'
 from party_time.rb:26:in `num_belayers'
 from party_time.rb:40:in `<main>'

Comment: I shared the fix, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`party_two` key is not referenced to a `Hash` so this is why you get exception. Try the following code.

```rb
def num_belayers
  kid_count = 0
  baby_count= 0
  kids_hash.each_value do |parties|
    next unless parties.is_a?(Hash)
    parties[:attendance].each do |kid|
      if kid[:age] >= 5 
          kid_count += 1
        else
          baby_count +=1
        end
      end

    #if the kids are 5 y/o, we put 5 to a group
    belays_kids = kid_count / 5.00

    #if they are younger, there are 3 to a group
    belays_babies = baby_count / 3.00
    belays = belays_kids.ceil + belays_babies.ceil

    puts "You will need #{belays} belayers."
  end
  nil 
end
```

Comment: That did the trick. So the primary error was due to party_two not actually being a hash. Thanks for the help. I am new to coding and am trying to get use to the syntax of ruby. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out of this bind.

Answer (score 0):

This code throws error when "parties" is not a hash. You are assuming it to be a hash and wrote the code for the same. Thus it ends up throwing exception when something which is not excepted arrives just like in your test inputs party_one is a hash while party_two is a string. I suggest check if "parties" is a hash and proceed else skip the code for that party.

Comment: Thats a big help. Thanks